# The character arm rotates the wrong way after 180 degrees

Tags: transforms

Currently, I am try to make a character rotate their arm by around 240 degrees. However, the rig decides to to take the shorter 120 degree way. Why does this happen and how can I fix this?

[image: 1]

Comment: see this answer to a question very similar to yours http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7124/2816

Comment: Thank you for posting that link. I found a solution after making an "in-between frame." I need to invert all of the values in the rotation section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simple. For the arm to rotate the correct way, it simply had to have all of the bone rotation values inverted.

[image: 1]

The values were previously,
W: 0.262,
X: -0.720,
Y: -0.604,
Z: 0.220,
but were inverted.